# Spring Stack web-app on Tomcat 7 not stopping (force kill required)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm having an issue with tomcat not stopping when requested from time to time and I have to kill the process manually.. I'm using a standard spring stack (JPA, MVC). This does not always happen, just about 70% of the time.. I have seen this on both Windows, OSX & Linux platforms...

Any thoughts why this may be happening.. In the below log, you will see 2 SERVERE log entries but from this question: [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered) seems to say that is not an issue with Tomcat so it leaves the soft reference..

Any thoughts why this could stop tomcat shutting down?

**EDIT**: On further Advice & Analysis - it looks like the apache HTTP client is using the DateUtils class, which in turns creates a ThreadLocal instance.. Our code uses the HTTP Client to class an external service... Surely this should be a very common problem if it resides in Apache HTTP Client as using this to call an external HTTP Endpoint isn't uncommon??

Threaddump below log output

Thanks,

Ian.

```
-2013-01-04 09:18:33,189 DEBUG [http-bio-9999-exec-8] view.InternalResourceView (InternalResourceView.java:236) - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/auth/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'auth/login'
2013-01-04 09:18:33,191 DEBUG [http-bio-9999-exec-8] servlet.FrameworkServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:913) - Successfully completed request
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
2013-01-04 09:18:33,409 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2] support.AbstractApplicationContext (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1025) - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'test-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 03 17:56:22 GMT 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2013-01-04 09:18:33,409 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2] support.AbstractBeanFactory (AbstractBeanFactory.java:245) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
2013-01-04 09:18:33,410 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2] support.AbstractBeanFactory (AbstractBeanFactory.java:245) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2013-01-04 09:18:33,410 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2] support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:433) - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@37f293d3: defining beans []; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2f701b4e
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$1] (value [org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$1@3f94bcde]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@3dfbb36e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jan 04, 2013 9:18:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

--Thread Dump-------

> at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$1.initialValue(DateUtils.java:220)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$1.initialValue(DateUtils.java:219)
>       at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
>   at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)      at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder.formatFor(DateUtils.java:239)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils.parseDate(DateUtils.java:156)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils.parseDate(DateUtils.java:114)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicExpiresHandler.parse(BasicExpiresHandler.java:61)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.CookieSpecBase.parse(CookieSpecBase.java:93)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec.parse(BestMatchSpec.java:135)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies.processCookies(ResponseProcessCookies.java:114)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies.process(ResponseProcessCookies.java:95)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:116)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.postProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:342)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:462)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
>       at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415113/threadlocal-memory-leak-in-threadpool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code uses 
`[org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$]` at some point. 
[This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415113/threadlocal-memory-leak-in-threadpool) tells that HttpClient may be issueing the reference.

So you need to look for code, that is using HttpClient - and be sure to cleanup any `Thread` or HttpClient related resources on contextDestroy.

Look at threads in your application, that use HttpClient, you should verify that these threads get stopped properly on shutdown.

Comment: Thanks - Looking at the class it does create a threadlocal however I'm not using this class, a 3rd party library is; how can I clean this up so tomcat will shutdown gracefully?

Comment: You told that a 3rd party library is using HttpClient. But based on your previous comment it look too much like that it's actually *yourself* who is using it. Note that the answerer has already told that it's HttpClient who is causing this problem.

Comment: I think you should also look to threads you started in your app, these should be stopped properly. (yes its not in the log, but maybe)

Comment: Thanks I'm thinking of moving from HttpClient - When you say "Stopped Properly" - I'm not starting any threads per-se, tomcat is though..

Comment: maybe httpclient needs to be update? dunno if its a bug. You could ask further on the httpclient userlist: http://hc.apache.org/mail-lists.html