# Removing threadLocal objects on tomcat threads while app shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, threadpool, thread-local

I am working on a web service and creating thread local instances and only want to remove them during app shutdown (once a threadlocal object is created for thread I want use that object during different service calls on that thread). As threads are created and owned by tomcat , is there any way to remove those threadlocals during application shutdown ??

Comment: Add a shutdown hook a thread and release thread locals, which only run at the time application goes down. `Runtime.getRuntime()#addShutdownHook()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [shutdown hook for java web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549924/shutdown-hook-for-java-web-application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clean up threadlocals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3869026/17300)

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 6 has memory leak detection in place, and Tomcat 7 has actual removal logic - it will automatically remove all thread local objects for you: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection

Ideally you should remove all objects from thread local after request is completed, since the same thread is going to be put back to thread pool and used to serve other requests - in this case thread local values may interfere with subsequent request logic, and cause all kind of security issues.

But if you're specifically looking to keep values in thread local for the whole duration of Tomcat webapp lifetime - Tomcat 7 will take care of cleaning it up for you on webapp shutdown, think of it as garbage collection.

Comment: I am using tomcat8 and I still get it

Comment: You still get _what_? If you get notification about memory leak detected and stale objects removed, that's expected

Comment: I get an error about memory leak in tomcat8. I thought that it's taking care of it.Also when I run shutdown.sh it doesn't shut down the tomcat I need to kill the process. is it related?

Comment: what is the error? it shouldn't be an error. and if tomcat doesn't stop you probably have something that can't get killed, db connection?

Comment: I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105803/tomcat8-memory-leak as the error was too long for a comment