# @Schedule Spring & HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager creating Classloader leak

Tags: java, spring, jboss, java-11

If I am creating a bean which has a `HTTPClient` and annotate a method in this bean with `@Schedule` -> afterwars undeploy the app (e.g. tomcat or jboss) I am creating a Class Loader memory leak.

If I just delete the `@Schedule` annotation, it takes a bit of time after undeployment, but then the `HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager` is GCed.

I assume that the `@Schedule` mechanic keeps a soft link to the class and therefor the `HTTPClient` (which would normally allow it to be GCed), but the `HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager` does not understand this and keeps open?!

Anybody having similar trouble or has an idea on it?

MAT: (I have 3 `@Schedule` annotated classes / methods)
[image]

(openjdk build 11.0.9+11-LTS, spring boot 2.4.4)

Comment: And the problem with that is? The class with `@Schedule` (the bean) will be a task in the queue for the `TaskExecutor`/`TaskScheduler` so the bean itself is also referenced. If that class uses the client that will ofcourse also stay alive (including all other instances). But I don't understand the problem you have, looks like you think you have a memory leak where you have none.

Comment: Sorry, you are so right. I missed to mention that the screenshot above is after the undeployment. So the problem is that after undeploying, the above seen contextClassLoader are left behind and not gced

Comment: Do you use a preconfigured `TaskScheduler`/`TaskExecutor` or using the default one? You are also using JBoss (judging from the screenshot). Looks like the tasks are scheduled but aren't cleaned and thus keeping references.

Comment: Default one.

Quickly checked with Tomcat -> it looks like I have the same problem, but would need to investigate further, if we think this is JBoss specific

Comment: It looks like a rogue thread is holding on to stuff. What you could try is to use spring configured TaskExecutor with the HttpClientBuilder instead of letting it use a default.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415935/using-net-http-httpclient-in-tomcat-causes-memory-leak

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager` will terminate when it detects that all operations have terminated, and all references to the `HttpClient` have been released. However, there could be a small lag between the time all references are released, and the time that the `SelectorManager` thread notices it. By default, this could be up to 3 seconds.

If you are observing that the `SelectorManager` thread is still running - then it's either because:

- there remain some strong references to the `HttpClient`,
- some request is still in progress
- the `SelectorManager` hasn't notice that it can terminate yet