# How to java ThreadLocal resolve memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, performance-testing, oval

I am getting following memory leak warning if using Oval library in my java project for json input validation:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [rision] created a ThreadLocal with 
  key of type [net.sf.oval.internal.util.ThreadLocalLinkedList] (value [net.sf.oval.internal.util.ThreadLocalLinkedList@2c215899]) 
  and a value of type [java.util.LinkedList] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. 
Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I am using following code snippet to vaildate my json input:

```
            Validator validator = new Validator();
            violations = validator.validate(object);
            if (violations.size() > 0) {
                String message = violations.get(0).getMessage();
                throw new InvalidInputException(message);
            }
```

How to resolve memory leak for oval references? I am using tomcat server.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869026/how-to-clean-up-threadlocals

Comment: Thanks but it looks patch work.