# How can we "disable" thread pooling in Jetty

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

Can Jetty Server be configured not to pool threads, but to create/terminate a Thread every time? I at first thought to create a simple `ThreadPool` class, but it didn't look like...

We're aware that it's not very good for performance, and we are accepting it.

Comment: What did you try? have some code or configuration?

Comment: I would try [<Property name="jetty.threadPool.maxThreads" default="1"/>](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html#og-modules-properties)

Comment: I just now tried the following, and going to look at how it works...

final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 200, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());

executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

final ExecutorThreadPool threadPool = new ExecutorThreadPool(executor);

final Server jettyServer = new Server(threadPool);

Comment: The Jetty `ThreadPool` class is based on the `java.util.concurrent.Executor` which implies a proper threadpool along with proper join logic.  Why do you want to do this?  I ask, as there is perhaps a different way to accomplish your end goals.

Comment: A no-pooling thread executor will actually consume more memory and increase your GC activity.  We tried this with an experimental Jetty 11 branch to utilize JDK 17 loom threads more, the experience was worse in every way than a traditional threadpool.

Comment: It's to kill `ThreadLocal` completely so that we can eliminate class loader leaks by some third-party libraries using `ThreadLocal` internally, which is out of our control.

Comment: Yeah, we know about more memory and more GC, and they are acceptable.

Comment: That server is not a very common web server, but an internal special one which receives just ~5 requests in an hour, and one request would trigger a heavy task (~60 secs) under a custom class loader.

Comment: In terms of that, it's still okay with threads pooled, but we need those all threads are sometime cleaned up.

Comment: Might want to read up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869026/how-to-clean-up-threadlocals

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I've read that kind of topics, but found that there is only a way with reflection to clean up `ThreadLocal`s "out of our control" -- which are by other libraries. (In our case, JRuby is there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminder: Jetty is a 100% async server, there is absolutely NO relationship of 1 thread per 1 request.  It is common for a single request to use 1..n threads per request.   The number of threads per request is dictated on the technology choices you make (Protocol choices, API choices, Servlet choices, 3rd party library choices, etc).  Example: you will use more threads when using things like Servlet Async Processing, Servlet Async I/O, HTTP/2, etc ...

This would be the minimum "no pooling thread pool" (a horrid concept that will actually consume more memory and increase your GC utilization by several orders of magnitude).

This thread pool implementation below is a bad idea.

## DO NOT USE IN A PRODUCTION SERVER

*Don't say I didn't warn you.*

This thread pool doesn't honor the fundamentals of `java.util.concurrent.Executor`, `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` and `java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory`, and will cause issues in random components: classloader contexts, java SecurityManager contexts, thread contexts, Thread Locals, and will likely break 3rd party integraions like spring, jsp, security, jaas, jaspi, cdi, session storage, session persistence, ssl parameters, ssl engine state, etc ...

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool;

public class NoThreadPool extends AbstractLifeCycle implements ThreadPool
{
    private final Object joinLock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(command);
        thread.setName("NoThreadPool"); // name your thread, helps in debugging later
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void join() throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized (joinLock)
        {
            while (isRunning())
            {
                joinLock.wait();
            }
        }

        while (isStopping())
        {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doStop() throws Exception
    {
        super.doStop();
        synchronized (joinLock)
        {
            joinLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getThreads()
    {
        return 1; // this pool is always in use
    }

    @Override
    public int getIdleThreads()
    {
        return 100_000; // this pool always has capacity
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLowOnThreads()
    {
        return false; // this pool is never low on threads
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Understood the downside of "no pooling" where threads are used not just request handling but also many other possible purposes. My ultimate goal is to clean up unintentionally remaining `ThreadLocal` in threads in thread pools, which are out of our control. My question might not be a good question...

Comment: But anyway, even though it's not for production use, your answer `NoThreadPool` is interesting to learn for me. Thanks!